# Message at the top of stackexchange pages "Stackexchange site name requires external JS from another domain which is blocked or failed to load."

Tags: support

All the stack exchange sites I've been visiting lately seem to have a red bar appearing at the top of the page which reads:

"Webmasters Meta requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

I looked in Chrome Developer Tools and noticed that jquery.min.js appears to not be loading from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1, and I have to assume that this is what the message is referring to.

Comment: Suggested solutions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90460/requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-error-with-googleapis-enabled . It's not the site, it's you!